# Opera versus Chrome background-image inheritance?

Tags: html, css, opera

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3c.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title>Opera test - css inheritance</title>
<style type="text/css">
/* theirs */
.theirs {
    background: #FF0000 url("http://www.wonderbackgrounds.com/glitter/backgrounds/glitter_background_b7.gif") repeat 0% 0%;
}
/* mine */
.mine {
    background-image: none;
    background: #FFC0C0;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<table border="1">
  <thead class="theirs">
    <tr class="theirs mine">
      <th>Month</th>
      <th>Savings</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tfoot class="">
    <tr class="theirs mine">
      <td>Sum</td>
      <td>$180</td>
    </tr>
  </tfoot>
  <tbody class="theirs">
    <tr class="theirs mine">
      <td>January</td>
      <td>$100</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="theirs mine">
      <td>February</td>
      <td>$80</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
</body>

</html>
```

I was trying to overwrite the background color of a TR, the code worked as expected on Chrome but not on Opera which is our target browser.

The question is, how do I write code in the "mine" class for css to get rid of the background-image. It works in Chrome and shows pink cells in all, but in Opera it shows the background image.

I can't change the other css, I want to clear the url but opera doesn't want to when tbody contains the same class. I took the class out of tfoot to show that it works in that case but not when class is defined in the surronding tags of .

Comment: Please post your **relevant** code here.

Comment: CSS specificity matters, y'know. See: http://cssdeck.com/labs/mry24dkq/0

Comment: @PeeHaa - **Follow** the link in his post. Code is there, functional and editable with a live preview. MUCH better than just posting a 44 line code-dump.

Comment: @Peehaa, if I posted the relevant auto generated code from Primefaces then it would take a lot more than 44 lines...

I worked this down to the smallest possible reproducible case.

Comment: @enhzflep Questions on SO should be self contained. What happens is that the link goes down and this question is useless. If OP cannot isolate the problem code that may just be part of the problem.

Comment: @PeeHaa - Okay, I see. So then I did & the you + the community a favour by posting the code here? You're welcome. Never seen anybody else complain when they (only) get thrown a jsfiddle link. You may like to address the way in which you started out this conversation of comments. :)

Comment: "Never seen anybody else complain" It's not complaining at all. If you think it is maybe you should stop using SO if you think it is complaining when somebody simply asks for code on a programming Q&A. "You may like to address" What are you talking about?? I started the conversation with Please post your relevant code here. What is wrong with that? What did I do wrong that you need to be like this?

Comment: Okay, point taken re: 'complain'. I hope you can accept my apology. I'm talking specifically about your apparent failure to read the linked-code, followed by (my perception of) your inappropriate highlighting of the word relevant. I looked at the code posted - clearly it was trimmed down to very nearly the smallest possible functioning example. Your highlighting of the word relevant gave the impression of condescension - that has been the reason for my tone. (I've watched behaviour like this for a decade)Thank-you for the discussion and the chance to review my approach and responses. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at the code, I see that you've left both classes attached to the TRs. Since they're 2 conflicting styles, you're relying on the order of application to get the effect you're after.
Chrome it seems, applies the styles in the same order that the selectors are applied to the element. I.e class='their mine' causes Chrome to apply their CSS then to overwrite it with yours.

Just this past week I was reading that it's not actually a part of the spec - the order in which styles are applied is entirely arbitrary an up to browser vendors.

With that in mind, you should simply change your css so that the class 'mine' has the same attributes as the class 'theirs' - albeit with the required changes.

Then, you can just give your TRs a class of *either* 'theirs' or 'mine'.

Expanding on the comment I left below, you could use the following html (taken from example page in your link)

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3c.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title>Opera test - css inheritance</title>
<style type="text/css">
/* theirs */
.theirs {
    background: #FF0000 url("http://www.wonderbackgrounds.com/glitter/backgrounds/glitter_background_b7.gif") repeat 0% 0%;
}
/* mine */
.mTable .theirs {
    background-image: none;
    background-color: #FFC0C0;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<table class='mTable' border="1">
  <thead class="theirs">
    <tr class="theirs">
      <th>Month</th>
      <th>Savings</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tfoot class="">
    <tr class="theirs">
      <td>Sum</td>
      <td>$180</td>
    </tr>
  </tfoot>
  <tbody class="theirs">
    <tr class="theirs">
      <td>January</td>
      <td>$100</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="theirs">
      <td>February</td>
      <td>$80</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: The problem was more the fact that I am working with Primefaces and the "theirs" is automatically added.

I have a common style sheet that I can add across all of the template styles, and I know my "mine" class is added at the end of the class for each TR. I was hoping that because it was last it would be the last to modify the style for that TR, but it doesn't seem to be the case. The THEAD seems to cause extra unknown int he equation. If the THEAD doesn't have the "theirs" class then the TR css works as I thought it might, but otherwise it doesn't.

Your answer is right, so thank you.

Comment: You're welcome. I guess another alternative would be to redefine 'theirs' on elements that are enclosed in other (specific) elements. For instance, if you gave the table a class of mTable, you could remove the mine style, remove the mine class and add the following css  `.mTable .theirs
 {
    background-image: none;
    background: #FFC0C0;
 }`

Comment: Sadly it wouldn't work as I define in primefaces which rows should be colored differently. And that row (TR) gets a new class added.